# What happened to my face?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I bought Dragon Age: Origins -- Ultimate Edition, and installed  it on my computer. Registered the game, registered the DLC it comes with, and go to create a new character.

Male humans apparently lack a model at all (they are just floating hair and a set of mysteriously floating clothes), and while the female humans had a model, trying to change to one of the other preset faces gave me the following:

[image]

[image]

Etc.

This is a brand new, clean install. Has anyone else experienced this bug and/or knows how to fix it? I just finished 2 days of downloading the damn thing, and I'd rather like to avoid having to do that again.

Comment: I fail to see the problem here.

Comment: @Raven what kind of graphics card? Was it overheating? That looks like a graphics problem. I have the lasted DAO installed never seen that.

Comment: @Viper I've got a pair of EVGA GTX 465's set up in SLI. I'm quite sure they weren't overheating though, as everything else works fine.

Comment: First opportunity I get I'm slapping a massive bounty on this question. *I need to know how to reproduce this bug*.

Comment: out of curiosity have you tried running it with SLI turned off?

Comment: @Xantec -- I have not, but, as mentioned, two of the preset faces work fine, so I don't think it's necessarily hardware related.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I failed to mention that. But yeah, the first and last preset faces load correctly. It's the middle ones that are borked.

Comment: it may be an issue with the installed files. you might try re-installing the game (or if it is a Steam purchase then maybe just verifying the files would be sufficient).

Comment: Similar problem here: http://social.bioware.com/%25252525C2%25252525A0http:/social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/58/index/5563187/1#5575163, and he did the Steam cache verifier and re-installed.  I don't think this is re-producable.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

EDIT: I have determined that the cause of this was my use of the low graphics setting in addition to / in spite of everything else. After upping the graphics, all instances of this problem went away -- and I can see all of Fereldyn in its bloodstained glory.

------BEGIN ORIGINAL ANSWER------

I started up the game later today, tried again, and found the bug still in place. I later get a notice that DA:OUE has downloaded a 130 mB patch. I even later get *another* notice from steam about DA updating.

The end result is that after restarting Dragon Age for the 5th time or so, all traces of this bug have vanished. Male humans have bodies, and female humans aren't...special. I'm going to chalk this one up to a hiccup in the graphics code...

(I did verify the game files as was suggested by Xantec, above, but that action alone did not fix the graphics glitch)

Edit: Hm. It looks like my troubles may not be finished after all...
[image]

I think there's something wrong with one of the dwarves in that picture, but I *just* *can't* put my finger on it.

Comment: If you want to ask another question there's the Ask Question button! :P

Comment: Of the six dwarves in this picture, clearly you're referring to the second dwarf from the right, who has a cleanly-shaven beard so short you can see his neck under it.  Not very dwarvish-looking at all.

Comment: That's a really messed up dwarf you have got there!

Comment: @Kyralessa: Yeah, seriously. What kind of "dwarf" is incapable of growing a beard that properly covers *at least* its neck? Shame on BioWare, they should know better. Worldbuilding fail.

Comment: Really... -- http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OurDwarvesAreAllTheSame

Comment: Hey, how'd Jar Jar get in your party?

Comment: 130 millibytes?  Damn compression, you scary!