# What's the connection between Dragon Age: Origins, and Dragon Age: Awakening?

Tags: dragon-age-origins, dragon-age-origins-awakening

I recently bought Dragon Age Origins -- Ultimate Edition from steam, and aside from a few [minor issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13441/what-happened-to-my-face), I think I will end up enjoying it.

However, I'm a little confused about what I'm supposed to be playing -- when I go to "new game", I have a choice between Origins and Awakening:
[image]

What am I choosing here? Is the difference like that of Diablo II and it's expansion (where the expansion is the base game *and then* the expansion ((though the expansion offers items / classes / etc. not available in the base game))) or is the assumption that one plays through Origins first, and then plays Awakening (like a true sequel, e.g., Mass Effect 1 to Mass Effect 2)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Awakening is basically a short campaign after the main story of Origins. Play Origins first, and after you finish, you'll get the option of transferring your character to Awakening.

Comment: I would recommend playing Awakening with a new character, if you import your Origins character you're far too powerful and it will be far too easy.

Comment: I disagree. Awakening is ridiculously easy anyway. You might as well enjoy your hard-earned backstory after playing Origins.