# Where did this guy's face go?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

I'm having a bit of trouble in certain areas with NPC's faces disappearing in Skyrim on PC. It's very odd because their skin and eyes are no where to be found but their facial hair stays intact. It's a very troubling problem, as you can see:

[image]

Yup, he's definitely seen better days. Is anyone else experiencing this odd glitch? Any suggestions to fix this issue?

**Update:** It's become an epidemic! Now no one has a face. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Oh, and I've tried restarting. Didn't help :/

Comment: Have you been putting pots on his head?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13441/what-happened-to-my-face

Comment: Faces. How do they work?

Comment: This game is riddled with compatibility issues.

Comment: @Pubby - hahaha no....but I wonder if I can steal everything in sight since his eyes are missing? Excuse me while I go steal from an eyeless man :p

Comment: A Bethesda game with display bugs? I don't believe it.

Comment: To cover the obvious answers: have you installed any mods or unpacked any of the BSAs? i.e., have you changed anything in the installed folders at all?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - I have done nothing. This is the original, untouched game I bought from Steam.

Comment: @spugsley Well then, that's definitely weird. Here's an upvote, 'cause now I'm curious what triggers this…

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - yeah, it seems incredibly random. In certain zones it's just one or two NPCs and in others it's the entire freaking town. Crazy.

Comment: Have you tried verifying the game content (Right click on the game -> Properties -> Local Files -> Verify Integrity of Game Cache)?

Comment: @deterb - I'll try that now and play for awhile to see if it helps :)

Comment: Have you tried updating drivers? Different graphics settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Various anecdotes on the Bethsoft forums* indicate that this is a symptom of a low-memory problem. This seems to be the same problem that causes missing or purple textures, stuttering, and crashes-to-desktop (CTDs).

One solution is to lower your graphics settings to fit into a smaller memory footprint. Another (if you have in excess of 2GB of memory installed) is to [enable the Large Address Awareness flag on the `TESV.exe` executable](http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=1013).

<sub>* No single good link I can find, just lots of offhand references.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem also, I fixed it by changing the Texture Quality setting from High to Medium.

I can't honestly tell the different, but it's cleared up all the miscellaneous texture issues I was having.

Comment: I'll try this later and see if it resolves my issue. Thanks for the input!