# Help! Where's my face?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Today I decided that instead of wearing light armor and one-shotting everyone with my bow, I'm going to use heavy armor, shields, one-handed weapons, etc.

So, I equipped myself a Falmer helmet, Steel Plate Armor, Falmer Shield, Steel Plate Gauntlets, and Steel Plate Boots :
[image: I have no face :(]
Aand now I have no face :(

How can I get it back?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where did this guy's face go?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35286/where-did-this-guys-face-go)

Comment: That's his face, everyone else in my world has faces and if I switch back to light armor it re-appears

Comment: Tried going no helmet/other heavy helmets?

Comment: Hmm thats the only heavy helmet I bothered keeping on me when I play again I'll try that

Comment: Stay like that - it looks badass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wear a falmer helmet as well and I cant see my face. The only thing you can do is unequip your falmer helmet. Or you might as well wait for Bethesda to patch that.

Comment: Actually, I think the Unoficial Skyrim Patch might have fixed it. Here it is: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=87144366