# So what happened to Geralt's body?

Tags: the-witcher-2

So I recently loaded an old save from chapter 1 after updating to the 'enhanced edition'.  Well umm... something ended up missing:

[image]
I checked my inventory and found that I lost all my armor:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: At least it didn't happen to your face!

Comment: @RavenDreamer my face is all I have left!  Well that and the pants.

Comment: Yeah, but you [shouldn't take your face for granted!](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13441/what-happened-to-my-face)